# I want to know Keypoints Annotation Tools

Tags: mediapipe

I extracted hands keypoints using MediaPipe hand pose estimator. However the predicted keypoints are not exact. so I want to reannotate keypoints to be similar Ground Truth.
Please Let me know Keypoints Annotation Tools.
But There is a condition, the annotation tools can use predicted values.

I already knew v7, but I don't know that it can use predicted values by MediaPipe or etc.